# Django queryset how to query SQL with positive values first, ZERO values second

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have an SQL query like the following:

```sql
select * from results_table order by case 
    when place = 0 then 1 else 0 end, place
```

This query sorts positive numbers first, ZEROs next. How can I write this in Django? Better yet, how can I write it in the following way:

```
Result.objects.filter(...).order_by('positive_place', 'place')
```

where 'positive_place' exists for certain models. I am reading about annotate but I am not quiet sure how it works yet. I need to write the annotation for every query. Is there a way to write annotation per query set?

Comment: Do you want to sort the results by numbers ascending, and then zeroes? Like this [1,2,3,0,0]?

Comment: An annotation is adding an attribute to each object in a queryset. Attributes can be further filtered and ordered. You can annotate a queryset using [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) and you can make it reusable by [calling custom queryset methods from the model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager).

Comment: @bdoubleu thank you! I used the links and found the answer.

Comment: @NicoGriffioen yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An annotation is adding an attribute to each object in a queryset. Attributes can be further filtered and ordered. You can annotate a queryset using [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) and you can make it reusable by [calling custom queryset methods from the model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager).

I'm having a hard time understanding your desired ordering but here's an example of how it could be put together.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Case, Value as V, When

class ResultQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_positive_place(self):
        return self.annotate(
            positive_place=Case(When(place=0, then=V(1)), default=V(0))
        )

class Result(models.Model):
    place = models.IntegerField()

    objects = ResultQuerySet.as_manager()

Result.objects.annotate_positive_place().order_by('positive_place')
```

Comment: I've filed this. Zero is commonly used in (positive) integer data for "not applicable" "not known" "don't care" etc. It serves much the same purpose as a empty string or a null foreign key and I can quite imagine wanting it to sink to the bottom not float to the top when you can't altogether filter it out.